# Angular inifinite loop calling function

Tags: javascript, angular

In a few Angular projects I have the same problem, whenever I try to call a function inside my HTML (that retrieves some value from the api) it triggers an infinite loop. In the example below it's getUser() that triggers the loop.

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let order of orders">
        {{ getUser(order.orderNr).emailAddress }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

component

```
private getOrdersList() {

    this.orderService.getAll().subscribe(
        orders => {
            this.orders = orders;
        }
    );
}

public getUser(orderNr: number) {
    return this.orderService.getUser(orderNr);
}
```

service

```
public getAll(): Observable<Order[]> {
    return this.api.get<Order[]>('orders');
}

public getUser(orderNr: number) {
    return this.api.get<void>('orders/'+orderNr);
}
```

I think it has something to do with the way Angular handles data but I'm fairly new to Angular and unsure how to retrieve this data without causing the loop. Perhaps someone more experienced can provide some help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an infinite loop, it's just Angulars change detection.

In development each change detection run also follows a 2nd turn.
Change detection is run when any async call completes (event handlers, timeout, ...) and can therefore happen quite often.

Binding to functions in the view should generally be avoided, instead assign the result to a field and bind to that field instead. Angular is extremely efficient checking whether field values have changed.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense but I'm not sure how to accomplish this considering I have to do this while looping through orders.

Comment: In `getOrderList` when you receive the orders, iterate over them and put them into an array like `this.orders = orders.map(order => { order: order, user: getUser(order.orderId) });` and then in the binding use `{{ order.user.emailAddress }}`

Comment: I used this:  this.orders = orders.map(order => { return {
                    order: order,
                    user: this.getUser(order.orderNr)};
                }); Which sounds like a great solution but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for me. User remains undefined and order is no longer visible in my html.

Comment: is `getUser` async? Can you please try to create a http://stackblitz.com reproduction?

Comment: I'm not really getting far with stackblitz sorry,
 but you can see my client code there anyway -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bkdj81?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Order is actually visible by just using {{ order.order.orderNr }}.

Comment: User will occasionally work when getUser is async, but most of the time causes a 500 server error.

Comment: Sounds like a problem on the server.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me along. I think the remaining problems are server side.

Comment: Yes exactly. The reason I thought your method wasn't working was also because my html showed intake.intake.attribute was false even though it was working.

Comment: Glad to hear you made progress